# Update Issue with my viewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, viewwillappear

I just give u example of my problem:-

I have implemented this method:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
NSLog(@"update");}
```

inside my viewController, but it's called anytime, how I can call it manually?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

`[self viewWillAppear:YES];` if you are in the object already.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be right to call that method directly as you are bound to do `[super viewWillAppear:animated];` within it. This method is to do all the necessary set up just before the view will appear. You don't know what kind of setup the `superclass` does. So it is better to package the part of code that you want to reuse into a different method and call it from both the `viewWillAppear:` method and the other method that you want to call it from.

Comment: @user755278 Did this help? Do you need further assistance?